# JavaApns in ThreadPoolExecutor?

Tags: java, ios, apple-push-notifications

To keep one `ApnsService` alive, I created a `ThreadPoolExecutor` to hold threads to send push.
Here is the code of worker:

```
public static class PushWorker implements Runnable{
        
        private static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(PushWorker.class);
        
        private String token;
        private String alert;
        private int badge;
        private String sound;
        private ApnsService service;
        
        public PushWorker(ApnsService srv, String t, String a, int b, String s){
            token = t;
            alert = a;
            badge = b;
            sound = s;
            service = srv;
        }
        @Override
        public void run() {

            
            PayloadBuilder payloadBuilder = APNS.newPayload();
            payloadBuilder.sound(sound);
            payloadBuilder.badge(badge);

            payloadBuilder.alertBody(alert);
            

            String payload = payloadBuilder.build();
                        service.push(token, payload);

        }
    }
```

When I created a worker and executed it in a `Threadpool`:

```
ThreadPoolExecutor pool = new ThreadPoolExecutor(corePoolSize, maximumPoolSize, keepAliveTime, TimeUnit.SECONDS,queue);

pool.execute(worker);
```

The program was terminated at:
`PayloadBuilder payloadBuilder = APNS.newPayload();` and without any error or exception. But, it can work if in the way below:

```
PushWorker worker = new PushWorker(service, token, alert, badge, null);

worker.run();
```

I don't know why the thread was terminated in the `Threadpool`... Did anyone have the same question?

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
try {
    Future result = pool.submit(worker)
    result.get()

} catch (ExecutionException e) {
    // actual exception in e.getCause()
}
```

instead